# Regular expression for numbers with one hyphen(1-5) and numbers with single spaces (1 2 3 4 5)

Tags: javascript, regex

How can i validate  a textbox where input should be in two specified formats..The formats are

For example: 1-5 or 1 2 3 4 5

See i want to enter the numbers (numbers only) in above two ways only.Either like 1-5(no spaces in between) or like 1 2 3 4 5(only one space in between).How can i validate and avoid the entries except in these two formats using regular expressions?

Please help

Comment: is 1 2 4 5 valid? also is 5-1 valid?

Comment: 1 2 3 4 5 is valid,but if we consider 5-1,Please try to validate in such a way that the smallest number should come first.ie, 1-5

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please update your question with the relevant code and tell us where are you having problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
^(\d+)(-(\d+)|( \d+)+)?$
```

The above regex should match your requirements

Of course, this is javascript!

```
var regex = /^(\d+)(-(\d+)|( \d+)+)?$/;
```

To validate:

```
if (regex.test(formValue))
{
    //Valid textbox value
}
```

Comment: While it's straightforward to fix, this won't match a single number. However, it's not clear whether this is actually required... I like how you factorised out the common first digit, though :)

Comment: Thanks :) I was going purely off of the requirements, also the single space. May be naive, but that's just what they asked for :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply,but it doesn't suits my requirement.I need to trim any characters other than this format.Please consider the string 1-9,there shouldn't be any character say space at the beginning,middle end,anywhere of the string.Same thing should be applied for the string like 1 2 3 4 5.

Comment: I've modified it to meet those requirements

Comment: This one ^(\d+)(-(\d+)|( \d+)+)$ is working.Sorry i tried this one /^\d+(-\d+|( \d+)+)$/ that was not working..anyway tanks for the help.

Comment: How odd! Sorry, I'll check to see what is wrong with it and will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Can anybody modify this regular expression in such a way that, i need to add single number also,say 1 or 2 etc..becuase i can't add single number when am using this expression

Answer (score 2):

```
^(\d+-\d+)|(\d+(\s\d+)*)$
```

Let me explain:

- `^` Anchor to the beginning of the string
- We then have an alternation `|` between the following:

  - `\d+-\d+` matches 1-or-more digits, followed by a hyphen, followed by 1-or-more digits
  - `\d+(\s\d+)*` matches a digit followed by 0-or-more spaces and digits
- `$` Anchor to the end of the string

Comment: The more the requirements have come in, the more it's turned into your answer! Apologies!